# Laravel Query Builder in Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I would like to know if is it possible to work in a model using query builder to make a join between 4 tables, I don't know how to use eloquent with 4 tables

this is in controller

```
$kurikulum = DB::table('siakad.tb_01')

->select('siakad.tb_01.*', 'siakad.krs_jadwal_aktiv.*', 'siakad.mata_kuliah.*', 'siakad.kurikulum_item.*', )
->join('siakad.krs_jadwal_aktiv', 'siakad.tb_01.staf_id', '=', 'siakad.krs_jadwal_aktiv.kdds')
->join('siakad.mata_kuliah', 'siakad.krs_jadwal_aktiv.kdmk', '=', 'siakad.mata_kuliah.kode')
->join('siakad.kurikulum_item', 'siakad.mata_kuliah.id', '=', 'siakad.kurikulum_item.mata_kuliah_id')
->get();
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) relationship documentation?

Comment: Eloquent discourages using joins and rather encourages using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) which under the hood do extra queries. This usually tends to result in less data transferred from the database server and also allows manipulation of related models as individual models meaning you can modify and save a related model by itself easily in code

Comment: if you can only give time to learn [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships), you can do this with 10% the effort than what you are having right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
$kurikulum = DB::table('tb_01')
->select('tb_01.*', 'krs_jadwal_aktiv.*', 'mata_kuliah.*', 'kurikulum_item.*')
->join('krs_jadwal_aktiv', 'tb_01.staf_id','krs_jadwal_aktiv.kdds')
->join('mata_kuliah', 'krs_jadwal_aktiv.kdmk','mata_kuliah.kode')
->join('kurikulum_item', 'mata_kuliah.id','kurikulum_item.mata_kuliah_id')
->get();
```